# Generate avsc avro schema from a scala case class at build

Tags: scala, avro, avro-tools, avro4s

I want to generate an avro schema from a scala case class.

Suppose I have the following scala case class :

`case class User(name : String, favorite_number: Int, favorite_color: String)`

The related avro schema is :

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": "int"},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": "string"}
 ]
}
```

Is there a way to generate at build time, the avro scehma ? using sbt for example ?
I saw [sbt-avro4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/sbt-avro4s) that permit to build a scala class from an avro schema, but I need to do the inverse.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You may write your own [**SBT _task _**](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#Defining+a+Task) using [**Shapeless**](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) generic derivation, it is totally possible to do... but, it wont be easy at first because you will have to learn a lot - [this](https://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/) may help you to get started. **_Disclaimer:_** I had never done something like this before _(although I'm wanting to do soon)_, thus, I cannot help you - but I know this can be done that way.

Comment: Never done that before, do you have an example of it please ?

Comment: As I said, I have not done it either, so I don't have any toy example... However, I know the [**Circe-generic** _package_](https://github.com/circe/circe/tree/master/modules/generic/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/generic) uses **Shapeless** to provide automatic derivation of _case classes_, but I am not sure that would be a good place to start. In the book they provide an [example of generic derivation of typeclasses](https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:generic) for product types using `HList` which is similar to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Avro4s` contains the logic to generate an Avro Schema from a `case class`.

https://github.com/sksamuel/avro4s#schemas

Following the project example:

```scala
import com.sksamuel.avro4s.AvroSchema

case class User(name : String, favorite_number: Int, favorite_color: String)
val userSchema = AvroSchema[User]
```

Hopefully that provides enough to get started on a `sbt` task if needed.

Comment: You are right ! I have never written an sbt task. I will make some recherches and let you know. Thanks !

Comment: How is it possible to store the avsc schema, by adding an sbt task ? I only found simple examples with hello world or something like that. Is it possible to do it in build.sbt ?